# True type font introductary question

Tags: fonts, truetype

Recently I used a true type font which contained spanish characters. I now want to use french characters from the same true type font but the characters do not seem to be there. My understanding was that a true type font stored all characters from all languages or at least most of them. Is this correct ? Or do I need to use a new true type font.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on the font.**

Any font *can* include characters from multiple languages. There's no rule that says a TrueType font must do so. It has more to do with what glyphs the font's designer wanted to include. If you require a particular glyph not included in the font that you have, you'll have to find a font that contains it.

On Windows, you can see all of the character glyphs that a particular font contains using the [Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) utility. On the Mac, you can use either the [Character Palette](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1518) or Key Caps.

A [TrueType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) font is simply an outline font specification that was developed by Apple in opposition to the bitmapped fonts that were more common at the time. This was a revolutionary approach that allowed designers a much greater level of control over their font's design and vastly improved both print and display quality. Compare:

[image: comparison between TrueType and Bitmap fonts]

Comment: Thanks for that, how do I open a true type font using character map ? There does'nt seem to be a file -> open option ?

Comment: @user470184: Is the font installed on your system? You should be able to select it from the drop-down menu at the very top. If it's not installed, you'll need to install it. That's a simple matter of dragging it to your `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder.

Comment: Thanks! Is the font name accessed from a property within the font file ?

Comment: @user470184: I'm actually not positive, but I believe so, yes. If you double-click on the font files in your `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder, the top of the preview window will tell you their name. I'm sure there's some way to change it, but I don't know it.